# Is it worth working at home to earn money? Can I earn more money working at home?

Tags: home, small-business, self-employment

I just started using an online money-making site... My question would be

- Is it worth working at home to earn money?
- Can I earn more money working at home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the right question you should ask yourself is:

Can I work at home? is it possible? do I have a calm, private place at home to work from? what will be the motivation while working from?

If you got answers to these questions, you will find if you can get money from home or not, because any place you can do work from will give you money, just work!

Comment: +1 @Amr ElGarhy - Did you know that you can edit your answer to fix typos?  Give it a try!

Comment: @Zephyr , I did update it long time ago, but imagine what, I just saw your comment now :) , and guess what, you can suggest an edit on any answer as well by editing it your self, this will be a great support and will make the website shape better ;)

Answer (score 8):

I don't mean to be rude, but if you have to ask if you can earn a living from home, the answer is 'probably not.'  Most people are more financially productive at a traditional workplace, otherwise more people would quit the jobs they hate and work at home or develop their hobbies into businesses.

Making a living from home requires being a self-starter and finding clients/customers who accept such arrangements.

First, be assured no one earns a living stuffing envelopes, being a mystery online shopper, or selling low to moderate quantities of stuff to their circle of friends.

A few earn a living flipping houses, cars, or shares, or stuff on eBay, but with considerable risk, capital, effort, luck, contacts, and experience/skill.

A few more find success by inventing something or developing a business. Once again, not as easy as it sounds.

You can look for professional work freelancing, or find grunt work on something like vWorker. But these are easily as competitive as the job market, perhaps moreso.  In the case of vWorker you are competing against people in southern asia who almost surely can beat you on price.

Answer (score 4):

It completely depends on what type of work you intend to do.

Are you intending to run/setup your own business? Or stay with your current employer, but work from home instead of going to the office?

If thats the case, then yes it is a good idea, since you will save on commuting costs amongst other things

If you are asking about working from home under one of those "work from home piecework" schemes, I would be wary. Many of them require you do an insane amount of piecework, for literally peanuts, so it might not be worth the effort (since you could earn 2, 3x as much in a supermarket shift of the same duration)

Comment: Working from home can seriously isolate you from the rest of the people at an office. If you have to work as part of a *team*, easy communication is very valuable, and being absent from the office may stunt your career growth.